# Impossible to do a simple zoom?

Tags: camera

i just want to do a zoom ,a real zoom , not a FOV adjustement

similar like using your scrollwheel when your are inside of a camera , but with the whole camera , so the border would just adjust depending of the zoom

is it possible to do so inside of blender ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the scrollwheel *tracks* the viewpoint, moving it towards or away from the target. If you are in the Camera view, you can either 'Lock Camera to View' in the *Properties* region > *View* panel of the 3D view and use the scrollwheel, or select the camera by right-clicking the camera border, and move it with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> in any of the secondary Transformation Orientations except 'Gimbal'.

If you want to *zoom* the camera, you must change the focal length in its *Lens* panel, found in its *Properties* > *Data* tab.

Answer (score 2):

There are three things people may call "zoom" for a CGI camera :

- Focal length
- Sensor size
- Camera position (dolly zoom)

You will find the first two here :

[image]

Comment: thanks what is the difference between sensor size and a focal length adjustment ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26256/relationship-between-the-sensor-size-and-focal-length